# can not injection/operation because 415 not support media type

Tags: node, tezos-client, tezos-signer

i have get the sign transaction hash, then, i send RPC request(/injection/operation) like this to brocast operation, this is my junit test, but it return 415 not support media type, i guess because of the requestBody must send a str, but it not a json, but i tried to change the content-type, it not in used.
[image]

Comment: Updated my answer with a code example. It seems that you need to set "text/plain" in the `Content-Type`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [TezosJ_SDK/TezosGateway.java](https://github.com/TezosRio/TezosJ_SDK/blob/cc341edd3163d2608cea424a0fb4e571cb80ad71/tezosj_android/src/main/java/milfont/com/tezosj_android/data/TezosGateway.java#L28) (**query** method).

```
    MediaType MEDIA_PLAIN_TEXT_JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json");

    String s = "a3...";
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_PLAIN_TEXT_JSON, s.getBytes());
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://...")
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain")
            .post(body)
            .build();


    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();

    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        String strResponse = response.body().string();
    } catch ...
```

Comment: thanks a lot for help me to deal the problem, i follow your sugestion to update my code, but it return me a new http status 400, message is "bad request", there is my code:

Comment: my code is very similar with your code, why return a  400 bad request

Comment: The operation bytes need to be valid ("a3...." is not valid, I just used it as a placeholder). Usually, the 400 status returns some details about what is wrong.

Comment: i got the reason why return 400, because the rawTransaction hash need surround with " to send in requestBody, i have never see this type of send requestBody, it is amazing

Comment: It is a JSON string.

Comment: Also, please accept the answer if it helped you to identify the issue.